# Matrix inverse of $\left(A-I\right)$ given $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am wondering if the inverse of $$B = A-I$$ can be written in terms of $A^{-1}$ and/or $A$.  I am able to accurately compute $A$ and $A^{-1}$, which are very large matrices. Is it possible to calculate $B^{-1}$ without directly computing any inverses?

For example, if $A = 2I$, then $B^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}A$.

Comment: Is there some additional hypothesis to insure that $B$ is in fact invertible? @Seirios suggests that you assume $\|A\|<1$ for some norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: Taking $A=I$ should convince you that this is not always possible. Actually, I can see no way in which knowing $A^{-1}$ would even be helpful here.

Comment: In my case, this is a computational problem.  $A$ is a large dense matrix with all entries in the range $[-2,0]$.  Since $A^{-1}$ is also known beforehand, I wonder if $B^{-1}$ can be computed as a function of $A$ and $A^{-1}$, rather than directly (an expensive operation).  I am still interested, out of curiosity, in special cases, such as where $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: I think a lot depends on the nature of $A$. Maybe you could use the Sherman Morrison formula and build up $B$ incrementally as $A-\sum_k e_k e_k^T$? (Of course, if any intermediate step fails, you need a different route.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a complete answer, but if $\sum\limits_{k \geq 0} A^k$ converges then $$-(A-I) \sum\limits_{k \geq 0} A^k= \operatorname{Id}$$hence $$(A-I)^{-1}=- \sum\limits_{k \geq 0} A^k$$

Answer (score 1):

In analogy with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a^{-i}=(a-1)^{-1}$ ($|a|>1$), one could study the convergence of the series
$(A-I)^{-1}=A^{-1}+A^{-2}+\cdots$.

Equivalently, if $C=(A-I)^{-1}$ then $C=A^{-1}(C+I)$ which could suggest an iterative calculation $C_{n+1}=A^{-1}(C_{n}+I)$ . This is esentially (if we start with $C=0$) the same as the series above.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is nilpotent that is if there exists $k\in N$ such that $A^k=0$ then we have

$(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}A^i)(I-A)=(I-A)(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}A^i)=I$ so the inverse is $-(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}A^i)$

If $A^2=-A$ then $(I-A)(I+A/2)=(I+A/2)(I-A)=I$

And more importantly $B=I-A$ may not be invertible at all if $1$ is an eigen value of A, and if $1$ is not an eigen value then it is always invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just found $A-I$ and then take it's inverse? I think it's way more easy. For exemple : $$A=\;\; \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2\\ 
a_3 & a_4
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ A-I= \;\; \begin{pmatrix}
a_1-1 & a_2\\ 
a_3 & a_4-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore we get : 
$$(A-I)^{-1}=\frac{1}{(a_1-1)(a_4-1)-a_2a_3}\;\; \begin{pmatrix}
a_4-1 & -a_2\\ 
-a_3 & 1_1-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: It might look easy for a $2\times 2$ matrix but what about a $10\times 10 matrix$???

Comment: You can always use the same formulas right? It's just calculation of the determinant that would be more complicated...

Comment: @moray95 - the OP is almost certainly computing a matrix with thousands, tens of thousands or larger dimensions. Matrix inversion is **very** hard work even for computers at this scale.